# summernote upload image: onImageUpload and sendFile function not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wysiwyg, summernote

I am using summernote v 0.8.12

my page with summernote:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>bootstrap4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#summernote").summernote({
      placeholder: 'enter directions here...',
            height: 300,
            callbacks: {
            onImageUpload : function(files, editor, welEditable) {

         for(var i = files.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                 sendFile(files[i], this);
        }
    }
}
});
});
        function sendFile(file, el) {
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file);
    $.ajax({
        data: form_data,
        type: "POST",
        url: 'editor-upload2.php',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    success: function(url) {
    $(el).summernote('editor.insertImage', url);
   }
    });
    }

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input name="subject" class="form-control" />
      <textarea id="summernote" name="body"></textarea>
      <input name="button" type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

the php file for uploading the image editor-upload2.php:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES['file']['name']) {
            if (!$_FILES['file']['error']) {
                $name = md5(rand(100, 200));
                $ext = explode('.', $_FILES['file']['name']);
                $filename = $name . '.' . $ext[1];
                $destination = 'images/' . $filename; //change this directory
                $location = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                move_uploaded_file($location, $destination);
                echo 'https://www.mysite.co.uk/folder/emails/' . $filename;//change this URL
            }
            else
            {
              echo  $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['file']['error'];
            }
        }
?>
```

It seems that the summernote page is not passing any info to the editor-upload2.php file because nothing is getting uploaded and nothing is appearing in the summernote form textarea.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks for reading this.

Comment: Can you open a web console on a browser and describe related network calls? Is there no network call, a failed network call, etc?

Comment: Thats what I'm thinking because I created a simple form on another page with a file upload that went to the editor-upload.php script and that didnt work either however if I create a form on the same page as editor-upload.php it does work

Comment: I realise on the simple form on another page I had named the file upload test rather than file so this is now working.

Comment: summernote is still not working for me,

Comment: I have looked and there is no network call when I click picture upload image

Answer (score 0):

The following script in the header of main page was stopping it working:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

I took 'slim' out of the url and it now works fine